# Email sending function not sending data

Tags: php, email, post

While I am sending any mail, this will return only name: from: message: subject : , but all these  fields remain blank..

```
<?php
$name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$from       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$to         = 'me@example.com';

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

die;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your environment, `mail` function accepts the headers argument as a string, not an array.

`mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php